# Why my class method works in React without explicitly binding it to 'this'?

Tags: reactjs, this

I am at my wits end, can somebody please tell me why this works, even when I comment out the explicit binding to 'this'? As far as I understand 'this' should be undefined if not bound to the class explicitly and hence this example should give me an error, but it actually does work. What am I missing?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 1
    };

    // this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    // this.handleAdd = this.handleSub.bind(this);
  }

  handleAdd() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
  }
  
  handleSub() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count - 1 }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Counter is at {this.state.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleAdd()}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleSub()}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Because you're using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They establish `this` based on the scope

Comment: more explanation [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/)

Comment: Thank you! I read this article, but not carefully enough apparently:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using the **arrow** function to call your method.
In arrow function `this` is bound to the value in the closest non-arrow parent function.

Comment: Thank you, apparently yes. I thought what mattered was how I declared the function that was invoked. I noticed now that indeed, if you invoke it like so onClick={this.handleSub}, it errors out as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are two `this` here:

1.

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleAdd()}>
```

Arrow functions take `this` from the lexical scope of **their declaration**. The bodies of class declarations are run in **strict mode**. The onClick handler is run without any binding and this would be undefined inside it. But with `this.handleAdd` being inside **an arrow function**, `this` still belongs to the instance of the object. Because it is declared when the object is instantiated.

2.

When `handleAdd` is executed, the `this` inside it will depend on its execution because **it is not an arrow function**. So :

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
```

`this` here will be equal to the object instance in front of the `.` in  `x.handleAdd()`. Hence it will be the original `this` mentioned above and so the object instance.